# Zend framework 2: How ot get all currency codes and countries

Tags: zend-framework2

How can I retrieve all countries with currency codes in zend 2 so I can use them for form select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know `zf2/library/Zend/I18n/View/Helper/CurrencyFormat.php` accept every 3-letter ISO 4217 currency code.

So you could just use something like that.

[PHP Currencies Array](https://gist.github.com/91media/1354456)

[ISO-4217 Currency Codes in a PHP array](https://gist.github.com/goldsky/4966067)